# Prove that $2$ is irreducible in $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{m}]$ $\forall m\leq -3 $, $m$ square-free.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am asked in my homework to prove the result cited above.
For that purpose I have proved that the function $\mu : R \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ defined as $\mu (a+b\sqrt{m})=a^2-mb^2$ satisfies the following:

- $\mu(ab)=\mu(a)\mu(b)$
- $\mu(a)=0 \Leftrightarrow a=0$
- $\mu(a)=1 \Leftrightarrow a\in R^*$

The existence of the function $\mu$ implies that $R$ is a factorization domain (although not necessarily a unique factorization domain).

With that in mind, suppose to the contrary that $2$ is not irreducible. Thus $2=ab$ with $a, b \in R\setminus{(R^* \cup \{0\})}$. Therefore, $\mu(2)=4=\mu(a)\mu(b)$ and the possible values for $\mu(a)$ and $\mu(b)$ would be limited to those in the set $\{2,3\}$, and as we can discard $3$, it follows necessarily that $\mu(a)=\mu(b)=2$. With that, it would be enough to show that $2$ is not a possible value in the image of $\mu$, and for that I tried to study the squares of $\mathbb{Z}_{\bar{m}}$ where $\bar{m}=-m$, but I did not succeed.

Is the path taken and the statement of the exercise correct? How could the exercise be finished?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is very good! You are almost done, and you can conclude as follows.

You are looking for integers $a,b$ such that $a^2+(m')b^2=2$, $m'=-m \geq 3$.
If $b\neq 0$, then $b^2\geq 1$, and $a^2+ m'b^2\geq 0+ 3$.
Therefore $b=0$ and you need $a^2=2$, which has no solution over the integers.

Comment: Nice! I see, thank you.  : )